# Izaya wants to be a god?

Tags: durarara

In the final episodes of Season 2 of Durarara!!!, if I remember correctly, he said something about wanting to become a God himself? And what did he mean by this again? The series did not explain it very well.

The quote from the Wikia, which this scene takes part at, as far as I can remember

> Anri confronts Izaya about his actions, knowing he was behind not just the incident with the yellow scarves, but also with the slasher attacks as he was the one who gave Haruna Niekawa the information she needed to start her attempted invasion. The two fight briefly but Izaya gains the upperhand and escapes. As he leaves, he angrily declares to Saika that he is the only one who can love humanity and that he refuses to share them with a sword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Izaya's ambition knows no limit. He's a normal human (unlike several other characters), but he's smart and cunning. He also has tons of information sources and some power over people, so much it makes him think he could become as powerful as a god. Izaya loves manipulating people, and that's kinda what gods do, so this is why he said that.